# Exactly K Successes in N Distinct Bernoulli Trials Each With Different Parameter $p_i$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have $N$ biased coins each with a different bias towards heads $\theta_i$. If I toss them all at once, I would like to calculate the probability that exactly K of them will come up heads.

I can see how it could be done recursively but I was wondering if there was not an analytical solution.

Comment: This is called Poisson Trials or Poisson Binomial Distribution. See the following paper on some techniques to solve this: http://www3.stat.sinica.edu.tw/statistica/oldpdf/A7n44.pdf

Comment: Thanks! That is very useful. If you write an answer I'll mark is as accepted.

Comment: Done. Made it an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called Poisson Trials or Poisson Binomial Distribution. See the following paper on some techniques to solve this: www3.stat.sinica.edu.tw/statistica/oldpdf/A7n44.pdf